# Como faço meu algoritmo de escalonamento de matrizes funcionar em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

Preciso fazer um programa em python que leia uma matriz A nxn e um vetor B e depois resolva o sistema Ax=B, a funçao q estou usando para a primeira parte é

```
    global n
n= int(input('Qual será a dimensão da matriz A nxn: '))
print(f' "A" será uma matriz [{n}x{n}]')
global matrizA
matrizA = []
global i
global j
for i in range(0,n):
    matrizA.append(list())
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        matrizA[i].append(list())
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        matrizA[i][j].append(float(input(f'Elemento [{i+1}x{j+1}]: ')))
print()
print('='*24)
print('Matriz A'.center(24))
print('='*24)
print()
for i in range(0,n):
    print(f'|{matrizA[i]}|')
print()        
ask= input('Os valores estão corretos? ')
if ask==('nao'):
    print('Refaça a matriz A: ')
    LerMatriz()
              
elif ask==('não'):
    print('Refaça a matriz A: ')
print('='*24)
print('='*24)
print()
print(f'A matriz B será [{n}x1]')
h=1
global matrizB
matrizB = []
for i in range(0,n):
    matrizB.append(list())
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,h):
        matrizB[i].append(list())
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,h):
        matrizB[i][j].append(float(input(f'Elemento [{i+n}]: ')))
print()
print('='*24)
print('Matriz B'.center(24))
print('='*24)
print()
for i in range(0,n):
    print(f'|{matrizB[i]}|')
            
ask= input('Os valores estão corretos? ')
if ask==('nao'):
    print('Refaça a matriz B: ')
    LerMatriz()
                  
elif ask==('não'):
    print('Refaça a matriz B: ')
```

Já o algorítmo para a eliminação está assim:

```
def pivoteamento():

for k in range(1, n-1):
    #pivoteamento
    pivo=matrizA[k][k]
    lpivo=k
    for i in range(k+1,n):
        if matrizA[i][k]>pivo:
            pivo= matrizA[i][k]
            lpivo=i
    if pivo==0:
        print('A matriz A é singular.')
        quit()
    elif lpivo !=k:
        for j in range(1,n):
            troca=matrizA[k][j]
            matrizA[k][j]=matrizA[lpivo][j]
            matrizA[lpivo][j]=troca
        troca=matrizB[k]
        matrizB[k]=matrizB[lpivo]
        matrizB[lpivo]=troca

    #eliminação
    for i in range(k+1,n):
        m=matrizA[i][k]/matrizA[k][k]
        matrizA[i][k]=0
        for j in range(k+1,n):
            matrizA[i][j]=matrizA[i][j]-m*matrizA[k][j]
        matrizB=matrizB[i]-m*matrizB[k]
```

E depois criei um menu printando tudo, não sei como imprimir um sistema Ax=B bem formatado e fazer o algoritmo funcionar, alguém pode me ajudar? Detalhe: não posso importar nada da biblioteca de acordo com o professor, apenas math.

Answer (score 0):

voce quer ajuda com fatoração com pivoteamento parcial?

independente do que precisar, pesquise e tente implementar alguma solução e traga o erro, que ai a gente pode ajudar a encontrar alternativas que funcionem mas aqui não é lugar de resolver todo um código ou projeto

Comment: desculpe... criei um algoritmo para escalonar qualquer sistema AX=B e rodar o conjunto solução, mas ele não quer rodar listas e me retorna isso: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: entendi, você não pode usar float na lista diretamente, tenta usar o map pra chamar o float pra cada coisa na lista, vou tentar exemplificar:

matrizA[i][j].append(map(float(input(f'Elemento [{i+1}x{j+1}]: '))))